# Photodiode showing triangle waves instead of square? (re: need op amp?)

Tags: operational-amplifier, oscilloscope, infrared, photodiode

I'm trying to visualize an infrared signal using a [IR receiver diode](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01ERPBF0W) but my oscilloscope is showing triangle waves instead of square for the carrier frequency:

[image: oscilloscope picture]

One of the guys at EEVblog said I need an op-amp because the signal is too fast (38 kHz) but I'm still learning electronics and haven't used any op-amps before.

Can anybody let me know what I need or point me in the right direction?

(I already have a proper 38 kHz IR receiver with demodulation, etc, but I'm trying to visualize the signal for learning purposes using a "simple" photodiode).

EDIT: Some other questions/answers also seem to indicate I need an op-amp with a sufficient slew rate?

EDIT2: Here is my schematic per request:  (I'm probing across the resistor)
[image: schematic]

Comment: What circuit did you use to connect the receiver diode to the oscilloscope?

Comment: I used the 3.3v (and also tried 5v) to diode cathode, and then diode anode to oscilliscope and 100 Ohm resistor and finally ground.

Comment: What kind of light are you shining on the photodiode??

Comment: I'm using a generic infrared remote control.  The 3-pin IR receiver shows perfect square (demodulated) wave forms.

Comment: Post a schematic please.

Comment: I've added a little schematic.  I'm probing across the resistor.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the parasitic capacitance of the circuit you have implemented. It forms an RC timeconstant with the gain resistor which filters out high frequency signals. There are [plenty](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1-d&q=photodiode%20transimpedance%20amplifier%20capacitance) of [resources](https://www.digikey.com/en/articles/techzone/2017/jul/design-transimpedance-amplifiers-for-precision-opto-sensing) to help you with this problem

You will need to minimize the capacitance and possibly get a faster opamp with more gain bandwidth product (GBWP). Breadboards are terrible for implementing circuits like this, even on a PCB traces can have enough capacitance (pFs) to make a difference, so short trace sizes are best between sensor and transimpedance amplifier.

Comment: Thanks so much.  There are quite a lot of options for op-amps and many different circuits from what I can find.  Can you recommend anything specific (i.e. op amp model and circuit) for what I'm trying to do?  This website (https://outsidescience.wordpress.com/2012/11/03/diy-science-measuring-light-with-a-photodiode-ii/) seems to recommend an LTC1050?